# Restart Jboss will get error when I added my created service(MBean) to jboss deploy route

Tags: jboss, service, jakarta-ee, snmp, mbeans

I created one service(MBean), I thought it could be start/stop normally.
I have my MBean in the structure as my previous problem had said:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177569/a-created-jboss-service-cant-be-stop-normallymbean

But today, I found the created service will get error when restart jboss.
First, the created service (a sar file for my snmp agent) can be put into the deploy route of jboss. And I found it really work, in my codes, snmp agent will start and listening on the port.
But errors come out when I restart jboss. If I restart jboss, I will get error:

```
 startup taking too long, not getting a response on 127.0.0.1:8081, giving up
```

And then I restart jboss again, I will get the error like follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.handleInvocationExceptions(ReflectedDispatcher.java:162)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:149)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:245)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.jboss.jmx.connector.invoker.InvokerAdaptorService.invoke(InvokerAdaptorService.java:251)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:245)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
        at org.jboss.invocation.jrmp.server.JRMPProxyFactory.invoke(JRMPProxyFactory.java:164)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:245)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
        at org.jboss.invocation.jrmp.server.JRMPInvoker$MBeanServerAction.invoke(JRMPInvoker.java:805)
        at org.jboss.invocation.jrmp.server.JRMPInvoker.invoke(JRMPInvoker.java:406)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:294)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:153)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:149)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:466)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:707)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: not started
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.shutdown(ServerImpl.java:617)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
        ... 44 more
```

I tried but can't find what is the matter but failed.
Could any body help me with that?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your MBean does not start properly. I wonder why do you need this code for:

```
public void startService()throws Exception{
    ...skipped...
->  Thread.currentThread().join();
}
```

What you are saying with Thread.currentThread().join(); is "make current thread wait until current thread dies (See [Thread.join() javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29))". This means the thread JBoss AS calls your MBean with never ever returns. Ergo,

```
startup taking too long, not getting a response on 127.0.0.1:8081, giving up
```

Any particular goal you are trying to achieve with Thread.currentThread().join();?

Comment: Georgy Bolyuba, many thanks to your detailed analysis. It really helped me to solve the problem.
In fact, the MBean I wrote was first designed as a jdk program. And I want to change it to MBean so it can be start by jboss. I didn't realize Thread.currentThread().join() will impact jboss.
Thanks again for your kind help!